# JavaFX binding with ActionEvent

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a small JavaFX application.

What i am trying to do is this:
My app has a TextField which the user cause to insert a url. Then you click a button to load the page. What i want to do is to have this button be disabled either when the TextField is empty or while the page loads. When the page finishes loading, the button is enabled again.

I used bindings to bind the TextField with the button, so when TextField is empty the button is disabled, using below code:

```
BooleanBinding booleanBind = new BooleanBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(url.textProperty());
            }
        @Override
        protected boolean computeValue() {
            return url.getText().isEmpty();
        }
    };
    loadButton.disableProperty().bind(booleanBind);
```

Now i want to also disable the button when page loads.
In order to load the page i use below code:

```
loadButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                //loadButton.setDisable(true);
                webEngine.load(url.getText());
            }
        });
```

Commented you can see the way i was disabling the button while page was loading (i am using a ChangeListener to enable it again after WebEngine finishes loading). But now that i used the binding to also bind it with the TextField, i cant disable it manually like this because i get `java.lang.RuntimeException: A bound value cannot be set.` error.

How can i use bindings to also disable the button while page loads?

Answer (score 2):

A `WebEngine` has a method for getting the `Worker` used for performing the background loading: [`WebEngine.getLoadWorker()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getLoadWorker()). A `Worker` has the [`running`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html#runningProperty) property. Use this property and combine it with whether or not the `TextField`'s `text` property is empty via an or binding.

```
BooleanBinding empty = textField.textProperty().isEmpty();
button.disableProperty().bind(empty.or(webEngine.getLoadWorker().runningProperty());
```

Also, as shown above, there is no need to create your own `BooleanBinding` to hold the empty status of the `TextField`. The `text` property is a `StringProperty` which extends from `StringExpression`. The `StringExpression` class has the `isEmpty()` method which returns a `BooleanBinding` for you.

Comment: Yes, i tried runningProperty but buttons where not switching off. Maybe i have done something wrong. I decided to do it indirectly by using a text field property.